# Running scheduled tasks in multiple server instances at same time in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, synchronization, scheduled-tasks, java.util.concurrent

We have a spring boot application and scheduled tasks.

We want to deploy our application on multiple servers , so multiple instances of applications.

How to configure spring to run scheduled tasks on multiple instances run at same time?

For eg : An application deployed in 1st server instance at 12am and task running scheduled at 12am.
The same application deployed in 2nd server instance at 12.03 am and since there is a difference in deployment task is also started at 12.03am with same cron expression ,and third one at deployed at 12.05am at task starting at 12.05am.

How to make tasks run at same time (all three tasks running in multiple instances need to run at same time 12.05am) ,so we get same results for all three tasks .

Comment: By using the same scheduling expression...

Comment: used  same cron expression since deployment is delayed for 2nd and 3rd server instances , scheduled task is also starting as different time ..how to make it run all 3 at same time?

Comment: @PhalaniKumar Could yoou be more specific.? Are you using Scheduler annotation.?

Comment: we are using @Schedule annotation with cron expression for scheduling jobs for every 5 mins...

Comment: Every 5 minutes or every 5 minutes in the hour. That is quite a difference (the first depends on startup time, the other will execute on 12:00, 12:05 etc.). Also when doing things with multiple instances make sure that the shared resources actually work and that those don't block.

Answer (score 0):

The cron reference is with respect to server time not deployed time of application..so all will run at exact 12.05 even they deployed in different minutes